# Install IPA with iTunes 11

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes, ipa, app-distribution

I have an IPA signed for ad-hoc distribution. I can install it fine with Xcode Organizer by dragging it to the device. It also worked with iTunes <=10 by dragging onto the device name.
I'd like to install it via iTunes 11 though. Dragging it onto the device name, or the app section does not work. Any idea how to do it now?

Comment: If you are using iTunes 12 check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26904969/1753005

Comment: Please refer the solution that I answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46520816/1722622

Answer (score 90, accepted):

In iTunes 11 you can go to the view menu, and "Show Sidebar", this will give you the sidebar, that you can drag 'n drop to.

You'll drag 'n drop to the open area that will be near the bottom of the sidebar (I'm typically doing this with both an IPA and a provisioning profile). After you do that, there will be an apps menu that appears in the sidebar with your app in it. Click on that, and you'll see your application in the main view. You can then drag your application from there to your device. Below, please find a video (it's private, so you'll need the URL) that outlines the steps visually: http://youtube.com/watch?v=0ACq4CRpEJ8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Sidebar is there, but no drag'n'drop of IPAs to the device. Did you try it?

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. I was used to directly dragging the IPA from Finder to the device name in iTunes. Now it's a little bit more complicated, but it works.

Comment: i do the same process for my app and works fine in one device, but just says will install in the other 2 devices, though they are added in provisioning profile and run well. Any idea why?

Comment: coder1010, my apologies I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you please try and clarify?

Comment: No need to show sidebar. Open Library->Apps, drop .ipa on apps list, open iPhone->Apps, push Install button of your application and sync.

Answer (score 14):

For iTunes 11:

1. open your iTunes "Side Bar" by going to View -> Show Side Bar
2. drag the mobileprovision and ipa files to your iTunes "Apps" under LIBRARY
3. open you device Apps from DEVICES and click install for the
   application and wait for iTunes to sync

Comment: drag'n drop for iPa works but it doesn't work for configuration mobile provision file.

Answer (score 12):

I always use the iPhone configuration utility for this. Allows much more control and is faster - you don't have to sync the whole device.

Comment: +1 for the most reliable and convenient way. Also had rather flaky results using iTunes (it often fails with pretty useless error messages) whereas the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/) works flawless.

Comment: You did not have to sync the whole device with iTunes either - as far as I remember.

Comment: iPhone configuration utility works fine, I'll wait a little with accepting your answer as I'd like to know if there is some hidden way in iTunes 11 too.

Comment: Unfortunately the iPhone Configuration Utility crashes for me now, on Mavericks + iOS 7.1.

Comment: Yep, crashing for me too. Yosemite.

Answer (score 12):

**For OS X Yosemite and above, and Xcode 6+**

Open Xcode > Window > Devices

Choose your device. You can see the installed application list and add a new one by hitting <kbd>+</kbd>

[image: screenshot of Xcode Devices]

Comment: this was really easy for me with yosemite and Xcode 6, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

for iTunes 12 and above (Yosemite) double click on IPA then browse your iOS device, on applist you will see the app, click the install on item.

Answer (score 1):

For iTunes 11 and above version:

open your iTunes "Side Bar" by going to View -> Show Side Bar
drag the mobileprovision and ipa files to your iTunes "Apps" under LIBRARY
Then click on your device.
open you device Apps from DEVICES and click install for the application and wait for iTunes to sync

Answer (score 1):

For iTunes 12, drag the .ipa file from the Finder to the Apps area NOT inside your device (in iTunes)... alternately, you can just double click on the .ipa in the Finder.

Important note: you have to change Version and/or Build number. Otherwise, you get no notice from iTunes at all...

Then switch to your device in iTunes, and install or update the application.

Then hit sync.

Answer (score 0):

For osX Mavericks Users you can install the ipa-file with the [Apple Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12). (Instead of the iPhone configuration utility, which crashes on OSX 10.9)

Comment: I'm running 10.9.5 and The App Store refuses to install this utility.