# How to run .app on iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, .app

I  have .app file of application I have mac and iPhone but do not have Xcode installed. How to         install app on iPhone without Xcode?

Comment: Use iTunes to install.

Comment: why don't you just install xCode it's for free if you have MAC and iPhone you must download xCode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

drag the app file into iTunes and then select your device in the iTunes . After that you can find the apps tab on the iTunes. Then you will see the dragged app file . CLick on the install and sync your phone .

Comment: i followed your steps but its  failed to installing message .

Comment: Did the developer given access to your device or not?

Comment: yes device is registered on developer account

Comment: No no I am asking Did he given permission in the provisioning profiles which the developer used in the app file

Comment: yes provisioning profile installed in this device

Comment: Did you installed on the device successfully ?

Comment: no its again failed to install

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39488/discussion-between-arpi-and-tendulkar)

Comment: clear instruction in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14161279/1083128

Answer (score 12):

Firstly You have to  Create .ipa File

1. Create a folder called Payload
2. Place the .app folder inside of that
3. Zip up the Payload folder using normal compression
4. Then rename the file with a .ipa extension

   After that just install through itune

Comment: is this working or not?

Comment: Not for me (iTunes does not have app section any more so you can't drag it in to iTunes)...

Comment: @Alfi u found some other solution?

Comment: First, the .app file needs to be renamed to .zip

Comment: Then, the .app FOLDER needs to be extracted and placed inside the Payload folder. Then steps and 4 should be followed as written above.

Comment: That's what is written in a Medium article on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. If you have an application package (.ipa file) that is signed with a provisioning profile that authorizes it for your device, you can install it in iTunes.

The other option is to jailbreak your phone, but I don't know anything about the details of that.