# How to open an .app file on a real iOS device?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, .app

I have an .app file, need to open it on a real iOS device, instead of iOS device simulator in xCode.

this is answer ( [How to run .app on iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448124/how-to-run-app-on-ios-device) ) is not suitable for me. Looking for an actual way

Comment: You can't. what you have is a simulator build. You need a device build that includes your device id in the provisioning profile.  You need to build this using Xcode

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use an airdrop to send your cell phone