# Unable to install api file from another developer through xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning

I can install my app written for myself through XCode smoothly.  However, I can not install an app, a ipa file, given from my friend through Xcode => Window => Organizer => My iPhone => Applications => Add .

There is a error message named "a valid provisioning file for this executable was not found."
[image]

Does any know why I can only install an app written for myself, but cannot install an ipa file from third parties?

How can I do to install an ipa file?  Do I need to request something else from my friend?  He told me he can install that ipa file from his device correctly.

Comment: I read that thread.  Does it mean I can generate the provisioning file for myself?  Or I should request the provisioning file from my friend?  Thanks for your comment. BTW, I have my own provisioning file when writing my own app, and it works correctly.

Comment: You need an ipa file with a valid provision profile. The updated provisioning profile should include your device. Your friend can do this, assuming he knows your device's UDID.

Comment: People must not have paid attention when duping this question. The question is about installing a *compiled* app from *another developer*, not building and installing your own app from source.

Comment: Regarding the duplicate question assigned above, that's different scenario.

I cannot create a new provisioning profile by myself to fit the provision embedded in my friend's ipa.  The only way to solve this issue is asking help from my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not install your friend's IPA file through Xcode.

Third party development IPA files are supposed to be installed via [iTunes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127576/install-ipa-with-itunes-11) or through a web service such as [TestFlight](https://www.testflightapp.com).

Your friend must ensure that he has signed the app himself and has used an ad-hoc provisioning profile with your device's [UDID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257577/add-udid-in-current-provisioning-profile/20257692#20257692) included.

Comment: I gave my UDID to my friend, and he sent me a new ipa file and a provisioning profile.  Now, I can install this app with the new ipa.  Many thanks for your help.