# Install apps on device without iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes

iTunes just dropped all the app syncing on iTunes 12.7.166. 
So, how can we install release or Ad Hoc ipa files archived with Xcode on the designated devices?

Comment: Apps that are not in appStore?

Comment: Apps archived and signed for release with Xcode

Comment: Why not install OTA?

Comment: You could try an ad-hoc / Enterprise distribution and install the app from a websource via "itms-services://" - see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561370/download-and-install-an-ipa-from-url-on-ios

Comment: The question is answered here.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/46224843/1152014

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just found another way, press ⌘+shift+2 on Xcode for showing the devices and simulators tab. Select your device and drag the .ipa to the installed apps section.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

**You can still install ad-hoc apps using iTunes 12.7**

Use following simple steps:

1. Connect your device.
2. Open iTunes and see the left sidebar for your device .
3. Just drag and drop your ad-hoc ipa file into it.

[image]

Hope that helps !

Comment: iTunes 12.7 **won't** let me do this. My compiled .ipa file (that contains a provisioning profile that includes the device ID of iPhone in question) cannot be drooped there in my iTunes 12.7. When dragging the file over that area the blue drop target outline does not appear. If i release the dragged file there, it animates back to the Finder window I dragged it from. Curious that it's different for you. The same file **can** be installed on the same iPhone using Apple Configurator 2.

Comment: Please recheck that you have ► got the latest iTunes version 12.7.0.166 ► synced your device with iTunes ► UDID registered and added in adHoc app provisioning profile

If it still doesn’t work. What is **version of your device and XCode** that is being used to prepare the adHoc ipa?

Comment: iTunes 12.7.0.166, XCode Version 9.0 (9A235). And yes the device UDID is in the ad hoc profile (it must be because the Apple Configurator app allows it to be installed and it runs).

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for Windows users. All the other solutions i tried didn't work for Windows.

I have been searching about the same problem for a few days. iTunes make obligation to update itself to iTunes newer version for ios 11 phones and iTunes 12.7 version doesn't have apps section so i couldn't download anymore my ad hoc app ipa file and provision files to iPhone.

**I just found out that there is an iTunes version (12.6.3) Apple published which won’t be prompted to download new versions of iTunes and you can use this version to download your app. You can dowload it from this link: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208079**

Apple say if you have a newer version of iTunes you can just download this one over it but I couldn't do it like this. First, I removed iTunes from my computer, then I removed the iTunes folder from my musics folder (you probably don't need to do that) and I downloaded iTunes for 64 bit PC from the link I wrote above. And with this iTunes i can use Apps section again and it doesn't force me to update it. So it works like the good old times.

Answer (score 1):

Install this application in your mac.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12