# iTunes12.7 cannot install ipa

Tags: ios, itunes

I upgraded the iTunes 12.7 version and found that I could not install ipa as before. The new version removes the App Store and the ringtone, which makes it feel awkward. I then found that I could complete the ipa installation by dragging an ipa to any list of devices.

[image: App Store not found]

[image: drag ipa to itunes]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install apps on device without iTunes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46194400/install-apps-on-device-without-itunes)

Comment: Please refer the solution that I answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46520816/1722622

Comment: This question belongs to http://apple.stackexchange.com and should be migrated.

Answer (score 7):

To get the ipa loaded drag and drop the ipa file onto the "On My Device" panel in the left hand column of iTunes and then press Sync & Done

[image]

Source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86806

**Update**

As the previous way seems not to work in all cases a better approach would be to use the *Devices and Simulators* utility from XCode

[image]

Then you can add and remove applications by clicking on the **+** and **-** sign below the applications list.

[image]

Comment: I cannot drag and drop on 'on my devices' via itunes  12.7.0.166 and iOS 10.3.3. curiously

Comment: We have the same issue, this doesn't work on all devices. On some we can install self signed ipas, on others we cant.

Comment: I have the same issue. I can install the AdHoc build on some devices and cannot on others

Comment: What are the devices you are having trouble with?

Comment: I am having the same problem.. i can install the app on some devices and cannot on others.

Comment: Hi @user2179059, I've updated the answer including a better way of installing your apps. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

Another way: Steps for ipa installation

1. Install Xcode IDE
2. Connect your iPhone/iPad to your Mac machine.
3. Open Xcode, you will see Window option on the toolbar, from there choose Devices option
4. A window will be opened with all list of devices connected, choose your device from the list
5. You can see installed apps in the window, with a plus icon, click on plus icon and choose your .ipa to be installed.
6. Once chosen click on OK.
7. It will install the app on the device.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to answer my question, but I could complete the ipa installation by dragging an ipa to any list of devices.

Comment: What do you mean by "any list of devices"? Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: I came across the same problem. I've added an answer to clarify with a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same problem and the solution to the link below resolved:
https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201593

:)