# With Apps option removed from latest iTunes 12.7.... , how to install adhoc IPA?

Tags: ios, itunes, adhoc

[image]

Now that after latest update from Apple for iTunes, Apps option is removed from Library in iTunes.

See Article Here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208075

How should my client, now get the ad hoc IPA, installed to his iPhone. Do the developers now need to deliver through TestFlight beta testing only?

Comment: Good question. You will get a faster and official response on the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46520816/1722622

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can still install ad-hoc apps using iTunes by following the steps under **Manually add items from your computer** in [this tech note](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201593)

The steps are:

1. Connect your device to your computer and open iTunes
2. Find your device in the left sidebar in iTunes
3. Drag your ad-hoc IPA to the device
4. Once the device listing outlines in blue, release the file.
   [image]

Comment: I can't get this working on for .ipa files on iTunes 12.7.

Comment: That is the version I tested on.  Is the UUID for the device in question registered on your account and included in the app's provisioning profile?

Comment: It is, but the app is bundled for adhoc distribution, and I don't think that includes the device UUID.

Comment: Yes, files saved for AdHoc distribution must include the device UUID in the provisioning profile, otherwise you could just upload your IPA somewhere and bypass the app store. But if you have this then it should be OK.

Comment: Try syncing your phone through iTunes first. Once it has completed sync process, then try drag & drop IPA.

Comment: The drag and drop are note working on windows. Any other option?

Comment: Even with the device UUID in the provisioning profile iTunes will not let me drag an ad-hoc .ipa file into the sidebar there. It does not turn blue (iTunes 12.7). The Configurator App does work however (see other answer)

Comment: May be, however Apple Configurator does not seem to be available for windows. The windows users still have no other option than iTunes.

Please make sure following in order:
1. Is your iPhone's OS updated to iOS 11 ?
2. Sync your phone with iTunes first.
3. Then try IPA drag & drop.

Comment: This worked for me with iTunes on macOS Sierra. My iPhone is still iOS 10.
But it **did not work on Windows**. By dragging the ipa over to the device in iTunes the cursor changes to _Link_.  But nothing happens. It does not outline the device in blue like it does on macOS.

Comment: I use iTunes 12.8 and an iPhone 5S with 11.4 iOS. In my case I copied the .ipa file from PC, went to iTunes, right-clicked on Devices name in the left side bar and selected "Paste". And that's it. The app was installed on my phone.

Answer (score 18):

Apple Configurator 2 software from Apple can be used for sideloading - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12

Just install the software, connect your device, drag your ipa into the Configurator, as simple as that.

Comment: Thank you so much ashwin

Comment: This seems to be the correct, new way of doing it. iTunes won't let me drag an ad-hoc .ipa file into iTunes.

Comment: We could also use Xcode Devices to add the ipa to the device directly

Comment: @Ade We can still install the adhoc IPA using iTunes 12.7. Please refer my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46520816/1722622

Comment: @theAmitom This is precisely what iTunes 12.7 *won't* let me do. My compiled .ipa file (that contains a provisioning profile that includes the device ID of iPhone in question) cannot be drooped there in my iTunes 12.7. When dragging the file over that area the blue drop target highlight does not appear.

Comment: My ipa is copied to iPhone and the 'Installing..' appeared on phone, but after that the app icon on iphone has become greyish and on tapping on the icon, I see the message "Unable to install [app name]". How to fix this?

Comment: Seems like a provisioning profile issue. Can you cross verify the type of distribution certificate being used and whether the device is added to the devices list

Answer (score 17):

Open `Xcode` and go to `Window` Option and select `DevicesAndSimulators`.

[image]

**Select your device. and click on "+" icon from the bottom.** 
[image]

click on + button will open window to select you ipa from system.

**Happy Coding**

Comment: WOW Boss! It was awesome. Loved to do it and its very easy to do.

Comment: Very simple and easy way

Comment: @jrhamza weird too :P

Answer (score 6):

Follow these steps to install an ipa file
[image: Follow these steps to install an ipa file]

Comment: Step 4 is the critical missing step from Paulw11's higher ranked answer.  Following the steps here finally allowed me to move my .ipa onto device.

Comment: When I set the option on step 4, it says all my musics and videos will be erased. Is there some way around without it being erased? (I am not an IPhone guy)

Answer (score 4):

Apple published a new version of iTunes 12.6.3 which can be installed over iTunes 12.7 and brings back applications management.

You can download it here: https://support.apple.com/fr-fr/HT208079

Comment: This is the only supported answer for Windows

Answer (score 2):

In itune 12.7 and onward.

1. Install **Apple Configurator 2**
2. Connect your device.
3. drag your .ipa file and drop it to apple configurator 2. (image given below).

[image]

4. now you will see app in your device.

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Yes, **Apple Configurator 2** worked for me. I was able to drag and drop my custom ipa file into the iPhone image. No need to use iTunes for this anymore.

Comment: Also, very good step by step instruction hwo to solve this problem with screenshots here https://codeburst.io/latest-itunes-12-7-removed-the-apps-option-how-to-install-ipa-on-the-device-3c7d4a2bc788

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and found that I can install the generated ipa from xcode instead of itunes. I used xcode Windows menu -> Devices and selected my connected iPhone. Then on the installed apps section, I click the + to locate ipa file and install to the iPhone. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use Xcode for the same, go to window -> Devices -> Select you device from the list -> Press '+' button under installed apps section

Answer (score -1):

There are many different ways to install the IPA or .app file on the device from your mac machine.

- Apple Configurator 2
- If IPA/.app is adhoc then using iTunes.
- Open Xcode -> GO TO -> Window -> Devices and Simulators

Please refer [iTunes 12.7 iPA installation](https://medium.com/@santoshbotre01/latest-itunes-12-7-removed-the-apps-option-how-to-install-ipa-on-the-device-3c7d4a2bc788) for step by step guide for all these three approaches.