# iTunes 12.7 AdHoc Builds and the iTunesArtwork file

Tags: ios, itunes, adhoc, itunesartwork

With the new iTunes 12.7 now excluding the App Store, is the iTunesArtwork file still needed or recommended for AdHoc builds?

I know the file was optional, but recommended for AdHoc builds, to allow for the App Icon to display in iTunes prior to iTunes 12.7.  Was that the only reason to include the iTunesArtwork file? Or can I know exclude that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only place that iTunes 12.7 shows any apps for a device currently connected to the computer is through the File Sharing section of the selected device.

Using a test app with no iTunesArtwork file, iTunes was still able to show the app's icon under the File Sharing section.

So there does not appear to be any reason to provide an iTunesArtwork file for the sake of iTunes 12.7.

You can still use iTunes 12.7 to install AdHoc build (see [With Apps option removed from latest iTunes 12.7.... , how to install adhoc IPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224843/with-apps-option-removed-from-latest-itunes-12-7-how-to-install-adhoc-ipa?rq=1)) but iTunes doesn't show those apps anywhere other than under File Sharing (if appropriate).