# How to generate .ipa from .app file in Xcode 9

Tags: build, ios11, ipa, xcode9

I am using Xcode 9. I did archive the build and got in to archive window/organiser window. From there we usually export the build. But due to some reason I cant do that.

On the prior version of Xcode, we can get into package contents and generate .ipa from .app with the help of iTunes. But now they have removed that option. Can someone help me to generate .ipa from the .app file that we have generated?

Answer (score 3):

The earlier way of dragging and dropping the app file to iTunes does not work anymore.

So we can use the organizer to create .ipa file in Xcode 9.

1. Create an archive of your project.
2. Then in organizer window select the archive and click on the export option.
3. Then select a method of distribution in next dialog box(I had
   selected development distribution).
4. Then the archive is prepared and development distribution options are presented. You can select any App thinning option or leave it as none and select or deselect other options and then click Next.
5. Then you will be prompted to select the appropriate development certificate and mobile provisioning profiles. After selecting, click Next.
6. Then archive will be built for distribution and you will be asked to review your applications .ipa content.
7. If everything is alright, click on the Export option in the dialog box.
8. You will be presented with another dialog box for entering the export name and location.
9. Enter the export folder name and select a location and then click on Export. Your .ipa file will be exported to the location which you had selected.

For more information/help regarding this way of .ipa file generation, refer to https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?34616,HowTo%3A+Create+an+.ipa+file+from+XCode

Also this link should help -- [How to create .ipa file using Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499125/how-to-create-ipa-file-using-xcode)

Answer (score -1):

From the other answer I see you can generate the .ipa file fine and the issue seems to be that you can't drag and drop your file anywhere as Apple have removed the applications page from iTunes.

From doing a little of my own research I think the current best solution (although I have not tried this myself yet) is to download iTunes 12.6.3 where the applications option is still available.

Please see the following link for a guide on how to do this: https://www.macworld.com/article/3230135/software-entertainment/how-to-install-itunes-1263-and-replace-itunes-127.html

The only downside I can see is that it is no longer in support as Apple only provide support for the latest version of iTunes (12.7 at the time of writing). However I guess that's exactly what stack overflow is for!

Let me know how it goes!

EDIT:

Just to let you know I've now downloaded iTunes 12.6.3 myself and I have my apps option back! Hopefully that helps you and you can then just follow the process you used to carry out. I have also found another post similar to yours with alternative solutions too:

[With Apps option removed from latest iTunes 12.7.... , how to install adhoc IPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224843/with-apps-option-removed-from-latest-itunes-12-7-how-to-install-adhoc-ipa/46578935#46578935)