# Can I send myself an iPhone app without installing in TestFlight

Tags: ios, testflight, ipa

If I put up my signed apk file onto my google drive and download it directly to my android phone I can install and run it.

Can I do something similar with an iPhone?  Or must I get the .ipa installed on TestFlight or something similar (HockeyApp, FlightFairy etc.) first?

Comment: Yes you can. and if your device is whitelisted in the provisioning profile you'll be able to install it. if you plan to distribute it and install to any ios devices you'll need an Enterprise distribution profile. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458014/how-to-generate-ipa-from-app-file-in-xcode-9

https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it via **ad hoc distribution** or **in house distribution**.

By distributing your app via *ad hoc distribution* you need to add all the devices that on which can be installed the app to the provisioning profile. Here you can use different devices like crashlytics, hockeyApp, diawi, etc.

If you distribute your app via *in house distribution* you will need to have an enterprise account but you can install the app on any device (is its important to mention that the device users needs to trust your developer profile in order to run the app).

Answer (score 2):

There is three way

1. Upload your `.ipa` to https://www.diawi.com, It will give you a download link. In this approach you have to add the devices UDI to your [developer account devices](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/ipod)
2. You have to buy an [enterprise account](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/enroll/)
3. Use https://getappbox.com/download/ it's an open source repository developed by dropbox

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can use https://www.diawi.com portal to send yourself iPhone IPA file without using test flight.