# how to Install App on device remotely iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am android developer but I have just started the iOS development it was quite a fun until and unless i faced the distribution time.

My app is completed. now I have to give/send demo of the app to my client, I did R&D and found that to install app on device I need a UDID. I have one device also with me I have already added its UDID in my profile, so I can test on it.

Now tell me if I ask my client for UDID and if he supply me UDID, then after it how can I run app on his device. I can not access the client device physically.

I know this has been asked so many times and I have read those question. but most of them are outdated as I can not find those options in xcode

I am using xcode 9.2 and swft 4.2 . Please suggest me a batter way of doing that......

Comment: Do you have a Apple developer account membership?

Comment: upload on TestFlight & gave permission to client mail id.

Comment: @hardikparmar yes I have .....

Comment: @KetanOdedra yes i know about it, but is not there any other way . Like taking out ipa file and send to my client via email

Comment: @SharartiKAKI ok then create .IPA file[before that register client device(UDID)] and upload it on diawi.com

Comment: If you have their UDID and add it to your developer portal and the provisioning profile then you can just export the IPA, send the IPA file to them and then they can [install it using iTunes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224843/with-apps-option-removed-from-latest-itunes-12-7-how-to-install-adhoc-ipa/46229114#46229114).  There is no need for diawi or any other external site.  Having said that, TestFlight is by far the simplest approach

Answer (score 1):

There are many options:-

1. Create adhoc profile then add UDID of client, then create IPA.Now create diawi link and share to client
2. Create enterprise profile, Create diawi and then create diawi and share it.
3. Go with testflight.

Useful Links:-

[How create diawi](https://qicesolutions.com/blog/2017/04/18/diawi-link/)

[Create adhox](https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/204270188-iOS-Creating-an-Ad-Hoc-Distribution-Provisioning-Profile)

[Use of test](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/testflight-public-beta-invite-links-ios-beta-testing-made-simple-97d2023791d0)

Thanks

Comment: what is diawi.com? is it secure?

Comment: @SharartiKAKI off course it is secure, and if you  more detail go to diawi.com use can check how many app upload on that.

Comment: purohit  is not there any official way ?

Comment: @SharartiKAKI using test flight provided by apple. and most of tester use Diawi,that's so easy way to do that.

Comment: You are right , I have seen and also got to knew that developers are using it, but dude I am not allowed to use it. I was asked to used official way. Isnt there a way to send iPA directly using email and he can install it?

Comment: This may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720764/install-ipa-with-itunes-12

Comment: @SharartiKAKI above link help which are provided by Dharmesh or use tool to install IPA:-http://www.i-funbox.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you have client's device UDID then you can send build using Diawi link, Simply follow this steps.

First of all add client's UDID in developer.apple account.

Then Create "Provisioning profile -> AdHoc" profile. when you create AdHoc profile at that time select Client's UDID. (See more details https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/204270188-iOS-Creating-an-Ad-Hoc-Distribution-Provisioning-Profile)

[image]

Using AdHoc profile archive project in xcode and export .ipa of application.

Upload exported .ipa file in https://www.diawi.com/

After finishing upload you can share build link with client.

Open this build link in safari browser(in device) to install application.

Comment: what is diawi.com?  is it secure?

Comment: it's tool to share application build with tester, And yes it's secure. you can install this build in device which is you have registered UDID in developer account.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/).

You can [create App on Appstore Connect and then upload one build to the Appstore using Xcode](https://codewithchris.com/submit-your-app-to-the-app-store/). After that you can simply use [TestFlight to allow Internal or External Testers to download the app](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5352-testflight-tutorial-ios-beta-testing) using TestFlight.

Advantages of TestFlight is that you don't need to have `UDID`s of users, you can invite them using their email addresses. Also, you can invite external testers by using the Public Link now. You don't need email addresses of users if you create a Public Link and share the links with the users.

Answer (score 0):

Apple beta distribution options are following,

> You must have apple developer account enrolled to give away beta app.

1) [**TestFlight internal testers:-**](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) We can direct distribute by adding testers apple email to TestFlight section in AppStoreConnect.

2) **[TestFlight External Testers:-](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)** 
   We need to add any email ids of testers, they will get invitation with a redeem code, testers will have to redeem it using [TestFlight app](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/testflight/id899247664?mt=8). User will notify for every build through TestFlight app. For External we have to submit for review for the first time only for every app version. Recently apple released feature to create a Public Link to invite testers, which you can share to any tester and tester can insert details directly from a web page.

3) [**Diawi Link:-**](https://www.diawi.com) You can upload build directly to Diawi, and distribute to testers whose UDIDS are attached with provisioning profile. There are some limitations to upload to Diawi like max ipa size is 100mb, expiration time 1day,....

4) **[AppBox:-](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/testflight/id899247664?mt=8)** To get rid if Diawi limitations, Some one introduce AppBox.  AppBox is an open source GitHub repo, I found it some time ago, not using it regularly so I don't have deeper idea. AppBox is using dropbox to upload and using link to share with testers, we can directly upload to AppStore as-well.

Hope it covers all options of beta distribution for iOS, will update answer for AppBox as I will use more.

Comment: My client do not have apple account, should I go for testFlightExternal ?

Comment: also is not there a way that user can install app using iTune ?

Comment: @SharartiKAKI if your client don't have apple account you can go for External option, and you can create a public link of that external build as well.

Comment: @SharartiKAKI there is no way to download beta release from iTunes, instead they have to use TestFlight app to install bets apps.

Comment: My problem is I have to send and made it available in one day, so I think using test flight is not good as it will take minimum of 3 to 4 days ? am I right?

Comment: See TestFlight Internal you can release immediate, and TestFlight External will go for a review and will take one day max (no 3-4 day now), according to US office time they will review quick as office start.

Comment: is there any way that I share my Apple ID with him ?

Comment: I mean I make TestFlight internal and add my own apple id and share with him?

Comment: you have to give them your email id and password(Not secure), or else you can create a dummy Apple ID for them and share access. They have to login using that access in iPhone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184861/discussion-between-dinesh-kachhot-and-shararti-kaki).