# Get ipa file in Mac with iTunes 12.7

Tags: app-store, itunes

In my Mac OS, iTunes 12.7 not showing AppStore. Apps tab is missing. How to see Apps tab, how to get ipa file from released game ?

[image]

Comment: I think Not duplicate. Getting .ipa is different. Previously we can download the .ipa's

Comment: This question belongs to http://apple.stackexchange.com and should be migrated.

Answer (score 11):

There is now another solution: Apple provides a version of iTunes (12.6.3) which supports new devices such as iPhone 8 and iPhone X which still retains the App Store.

Apple Configurator 2 works well for me, but I’m adding this answer for those who would prefer to use iTunes or can’t use Apple Configurator (Windows users) Source: https://9to5mac.com/2017/10/09/apple-itunes-apps-focused-removed-stopgap/

Download: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208079

Edit: You can have iTunes 12.7 and iTunes 12.6.3 installed side-by-side.

Install iTunes 12.6.3 from the links above.
Copy the iTunes app and paste it to where you want, rename if necessary.
Hold Option and double click iTunes. Create a new library in a separate location. iTunes 12.6.3 and iTunes 12.7 can't use the same library because iTunes 12.7 will update the file and iTunes 12.6.3 won't be able to understand it.
Manually download the latest iTunes from Apple's website and run the installer to update your main copy of iTunes.
(Optional) Change your iTunes 12.6.3 icon to a different icon to help distinguish between the two. (Right-click, Get Info, drag new icon onto existing icon).
Important: You will need to Option-Open each time you switch versions so that you can select the correct library and don't update the older library to 12.7 format.

form:
[iphone - How do I download an iOS App (IPA) file to my Mac after iTunes 12.7 update? - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298391/how-do-i-download-an-ios-app-ipa-file-to-my-mac-after-itunes-12-7-update)

Answer (score 6):

Now in iTunes 12.7 AppStore removed.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208075

Comment: Now in iTunes 12.6 option is gone to download .ipa from the Appstore. Do not know there is any alternative

Comment: @codester hey its still possible with iTunes 12.6.2, just now I downloaded game and dragged ipa to desktop :)

Comment: @codester see here..downloaded ipa in desktop https://app.box.com/s/4tl0mmqd2lbqeix67w5v0ci0q2lxq4yj

Comment: Thanks, I was using old itunes.

Comment: @codester how do you install the old er iTunes? My iTunes 12.6.2 can't be installed and reason it shows is that the newer iTunes is on my Mac. And when I try to remove the newer one, my Mac tell me that it can't be removed because macOS needs it.

Comment: @yuchen I have 2 Mac OS in my system. I installed iTunes 12.6 in old Mac. Then restarted to new Mac OS. This time Mac not allowed me to launch old iTunes. Then I renamed  'iTunes Library.itl' file to 'iTunes Library_OLD.itl' in /Users/gururajtallur/Music/iTunes/iTunes Library.itl , Then I successfully launched old iTunes 12.6 in latest Mac :)

Comment: @yuchen I'm using linux and you can consider my solution. Use Windows in VirtualBox, install old iTunes, and attach USB device to the VM.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the app IPA of an installed app from your iOS device to your Mac using **iMazing app** for Mac. It worked for me. Follow the steps in [this](https://imazing.com/guides/how-to-manage-apps-without-itunes)
link. Download link for Mac [here](https://imazing.com/download/macos). It is also available for Windows as well.

Comment: useless app. don't download it!!

Comment: @MaksimKniazev I were in a similar situation and got the IPA from a released app using iMazing. It worked well for me. May I know the reason, why it is useless?

Comment: Latest version I downloaded required to use back up device first. It was inconvenient for me and took more time. My best solution was to use older version of iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

See [How do I download an iOS App (IPA) file to my Mac after iTunes 12.7 update?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298391/how-do-i-download-an-ios-app-ipa-file-to-my-mac-after-itunes-12-7-update) on Ask Different Apple StackExchange for multiple solutions:

- Downloading the app on an iOS device and using Apple Configurator to retrieve it on the Mac.
- Installing iTunes 12.6.3, which supports iOS 11 devices but retains the App Store. (You can even have the two versions side-by-side on a Mac if you don't mind switching libraries when switching versions).

Answer (score 0):

Apple has removed the Apps tab. So now, you can not see the released game IPA. If needed you can always download older iTunes to get back the functionality.

But you can still install ad-hoc apps using iTunes 12.7. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46520816/1722622

Answer (score -4):

If you have XCode 9 and the Project, then you can Export and get ipa.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412771/2271631