# iTunes 12 Install IPA

Tags: ios, iphone, installation, itunes, itunes-app

I'm running into an issue with the latest iTunes 12 release (12.7.0.166) where on one iPhone I'm able to drag and drop an .IPA onto the device listed and it installs on the device fine. However, with the other iPhone I follow the same process and it doesn't seem to want to work or highlight the device when the .IPA is hovered over it.

Any ideas why this would work on one device, but not the other? Is there a setting maybe I'm missing somewhere on one of the devices?

Comment: Please refer the solution that I answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46520816/1722622

Comment: Do you have the UDID on the other phone added? If not please add and try again. Hope it works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install apps on device without iTunes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46194400/install-apps-on-device-without-itunes)

Answer (score 1):

In itune 12.7 and onward.

1. Install **Apple Configurator 2** from App Store.
2. Connect your device.
3. drag your .ipa file and drop it to apple configurator 2. (image given below).

[image]

4. now you will see app in your device.

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with two iPhones (One running 9.3.5 and 10.3.3).

The first thing I did was make sure both phones had Manually Manage Music and Videos checked (Under Summary -> Options). (Didn't have a direct effect but may help?)

I then updated the phone with 9.3.5 to the latest iOS (10.3.3) and I was then able to install it on both phones using the method you mentioned.

If you can't update a phone on an older iOS then you can re-install older versions of iTunes here: https://support.apple.com/downloads/itunes (Although this is a work around imho)

Answer (score 0):

iTunes 12 hid the "APP" section, but still, you can install ipa file through iTunes.

Drag and drop the ipa file into "**Devices**" section. It will auto sync and install the application to your device.

[image]