# Install IPA with iTunes 12.7

Tags: ios, itunes

How can i install Ad-Hoc ipa file using iTunes? Seems apple removed Apps section in newer version as shown in below image.

[image]

Comment: Try the method here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86806

Comment: Apple Configurator 2 software from Apple can be used for sideloading - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12

Just install the software, connect your device, drag your ipa into the Configurator, as simple as that.

Comment: Solve using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46520816/1722622

Answer (score 4):

iOS App management was removed from iTunes with version 12.7.

**[Updated answer 10/09/2017]**
Apple published a new version of iTunes 12.6.3 which can be installed over iTunes 12.7 and brings back applications management.

You can download it here: https://support.apple.com/fr-fr/HT208079

**[Original answer]**
You can try to reinstall iTunes 12.6 or try with another tool like iMazing.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12