# How can I install adhoc .ipa build with iTunes because new iTunes version 12.7.0.166 did not have Apps option

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes

New iTunes version 12.7.0.166 did not have Apps option as you can see in the attached screenshot of the new iTunes
[image]

Comment: Please refer the solution that I answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46520816/1722622

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install them using Xcode under Window -> Devices and Simulators.
Just drag and drop your .ipa over a device you have and that's it.